How to add form validation to WooCommerce Extension
Currently I have a working Woocommerce extension which accepts user inputs and saves them successfully as options in the wp_options table. Now I was wondering if it is possible to reject some inputs from users if it falls outside pre-determined input cases.
What I have is
     add_filter('woocommerce_get_sections_advanced', array($this,"wc_bulk_sms"));
     add_filter('woocommerce_get_settings_advanced', array($this,"wc_bulk_sms_settings"),10,2);
     add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', array($this,"tp_order_status"),10,3);
            

    //Wc sections
    function wc_bulk_sms($sections){
        $sections['wctpbulksms'] = __('MOBILE SASA Transactional SMS','wordpress');
        return $sections;
    }
        
    function wc_bulk_sms_settings($settings, $current_section){
        if ($current_section == 'wctpbulksms'){
            $tp_sms_settings = array();
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('TEST Settings','wordpress'),'type'=>'title','id'=>'wctpbulksms');
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Enable/Disable','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_enable','type'=>'checkbox','desc'=>__('Enable','wordpress'));
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Sender ID','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_senderid','type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'e.g TESTER');
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Api Token','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_apitoken','type'=>'text');
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Admin Number','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_adminnumber','type'=>'text','desc'=>__('Admin Number will receive a text on every order processing status','wordpress'), 'placeholder'=>'e.g 0729123456');
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Receive Admin SMS','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_ordernewadmin','type'=>'checkbox','desc'=>__('Send SMS','wordpress'));
            $tp_sms_settings[] = array('name'=>__('Admin Placed Order SMS','wordpress'),'id'=>'wctpbulksms_ordernewadminsms','type'=>'textarea','desc'=>__('Order shortcodes: {name} {orderid} {total} {phone}','wordpress'),'placeholder'=>__('e.g Hello Admin, {name} has placed an order #{orderid}','wordpress'));
       }

Note that I have shortcodes such as {name}, {orderid}, {total}, {phone} which all work successfully. What I want to prevent is if an admin gets the silly idea to use something like {firstname} which essentially will do nothing but they may not know that hence I want some sort of validation which prevents anything within braces except the four approved shortcodes.
I would like to run this validation either on typing within the input and display an error immediately or when a user tries to save the settings, an error should be thrown and the settings will not be saved.
